# Change table cell text color and background of row based on text in the table without table tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a table which has column  that contain status. Two statuses, "Open" and "Closed" are in the last column of the table.

I would like to change the cell text color of "Closed" to red and the row backround color of  "Open"  to green.

Any advice would be helpful.

EDIT: I would like to find out how to assign above described colors based on text context (Open, Closed) in the last column of the table with javascript.

HTML:

```
<div id="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">b</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">c</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">Open</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">Closed</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">c</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">d</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">e</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">Closed</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">b</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">c</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="dataText">Open</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#table {
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;  
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy!

```
<div class="row open">
```

and

```
.row.open { background: green; }
```

for the row, and

```
<div class="cell closed">
```

and

```
.dataText.closed { color: red; }
```

for the cell

A quick'n'dirty(!) solution to iterate over each row and add the classes dynamically:

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("div#table .row"); // get all rows
[].forEach.call(rows, function(row) { // iterate over each row
  var cell = row.querySelector(".cell:last-child .dataText"); // get the dataText Element in the last cell in each row
  var cellContent = cell.innerHTML; // read out cell content
  if (cellContent === "Open") { // it says "Open"
      row.classList.add("open"); // add "open" class to row
      cell.classList.add("open"); // add "open" class to status cell
  } else if (cellContent === "Closed") { // it says "Closed"
      row.classList.add("closed"); // add "closed" class to row
      cell.classList.add("closed");// add "closed" class to status cell
  }
});
```

Untested, but should work.

Comment: I forgot to add that the statuses are loaded dynamically, it's not know what are the statues in the cells until the page is loaded. The only text of status is known (Open, Closed). So it is necessary to assign the classes depending on text in the last column. This is what I want to find out.

Comment: Actually, this JS code won't work, because `cellContent` will contain the `div` HTML as well.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, thats why I said "quick'n'dirty" and "untested". Actually ran this code and updated my answer. Now it should work!

Comment: Almost there! I wanted change background color for row :"Open" and text color for "Closed" so should be: `  if (cellContent === "Closed") {
      cell.classList.add("closed");
  } else if (cellContent === "Open") {
      row.classList.add("open");` But it is applying only the classes to the first two rows of the table. The last rows have classes unchanged.

Comment: Ahhh damn you are right, so it seems I cannot read the specs as well ;) But I think you now got a hang on it and should be able to solve your problem. Yeah, you can still mark my answer despite the little flaws ;)

Comment: Should work as intended. Do you mean you want to format _both_ cell and rows in _both_ cases "Open" and "Closed"? Of course then the code has to be adapted, but that should be easy.

Comment: @frontend_dev As I said in the beginning, this won't work, `cell.innerHTML` will get the whole HTML content including `<div class="" ....>`, it will never be = to `"Open"` or `"Closed"`. The provided solution doesn't work.

Comment: @frontend_dev This is beyond my js knowledge, I'm learning based on the examples. Thanks for help already marked your answer. Yes I want to format all "Open" and "Close" cases despite of the table size - the table can have more columns and more rows in the future. The only what will not change that's the last column statuses.

Comment: chsdk, this does work, try it. In case you did not notice I updated my answer. @Szmerek, not exactly sure what you want, but I updated my answer so that _both_ the row _and_ the cell get their classes. You can then use your CSS to freely style them.

Comment: @Szmerek, I also added some comments for better understanding what the code actually does

Comment: and another thing: this code can break if you have something else in your code with the class "row" - like another identical table - so you have to be careful, maybe it makes sense to narrow down the selector in the querySelectorAll statement.

Comment: @frontend_dev I can understand what code does and know how to style it. Thanks for comments. Have tested and still your code is working only for two rows of the table. For the rest of the rows it isn't.

Comment: @frontend_dev I have prepared page only with the code I posted. And testing it there.There are no other tables.

Comment: I don't get it. Just ran the code here locally with the HTML you provided above and I get four rows:

Comment: "row open" "row closed" "row closed" "row open", that seems to about what it should do, or do I get something wrong?

Comment: I don't get it either. It's working on jsfiddle but not on my clean without any other code html.

Comment: @frontend_dev Works perfect just figured out that my cat was walking over my keyboard and changed the last rows table classes :) Many thanks!

Comment: @frontend_dev Edited your CSS to return what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`document.querySelctorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** along with this selector `.cell:last-child .dataText` to get all the last columns , check over their text contents, and change their background color accordingly.

This is how should be your code:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell:last-child .dataText")).forEach(function(cell) {
  //We select the whole row with cell.parentNode.parentNode
  if (cell.textContent == "Open")
    cell.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  else if (cell.textContent == "Closed")
    cell.style.color = "red";
});
```

**Demo:**

This is a live working Demo:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell:last-child .dataText")).forEach(function(cell) {
  if (cell.textContent == "Open")
    cell.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  else if (cell.textContent == "Closed")
    cell.style.color = "red";
});
```

```css
#table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="dataText">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="dataText">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="dataText">c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="dataText">Open</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="dataText">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="dataText">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="dataText">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="dataText">Closed</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But be aware that this code is ES2015 and might not run in older Browsers.

Comment: @frontend_dev Yes you are right, but there's always a ployfill for it, anyway there's wouldn't be much differences and the logic is always the same.

Comment: Yeah, but using a polyfill for such a small snippet sounds a bit like overkill. Other than that, of course everyone should switch to ES6 at least when doing more complex stuff.

Comment: I didn't recommended using the MDN polyfill, but with the same logic the code can be changed so it works on older browsers, which doesn't support ES6.

Comment: And btw seems like your code won't exactly do what the OP wanted

Comment: nope. You only change the *text color* in both cases

Comment: @frontend_dev Anyway, I changed my answer, and now it works perfectl. :)

Comment: @chsdk Yes it's working almost as intended but only changing background color of the cell (Open) instead of entrire row.

Answer (score 0):

Before `</body>` place:

```
<script>
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.cell:last-of-type'))
  .forEach(function (cell) {
    cell.parentElement.className = 'row ' + (cell.innerText === 'Open' ? 'open' : 'closed');
  });
</script>
```

And to your CSS append:

```
.row.open {
  background: green;
}
.row.closed {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span style="color:green">open</span>
```